# Canvas: curved line without breaks

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have implemented line drawing in `canvas`. But I faced a problem:


when line width is small (3), curved line looks nice;

when line width is large (20), curved line looks not good because of breaks.

[image]

```
canvas.node.onmousemove = function (e) {
         if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
             return;
         }
         var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
         var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(canvas.lastX, canvas.lastY);
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
         ctx.lineWidth = self.lineWidth();
         ctx.lineTo(x, y);
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.closePath();
         canvas.lastX = x;
         canvas.lastY = y;
};
canvas.node.onmousedown = function (e) {
         canvas.isDrawing = true;
         canvas.lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
         canvas.lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
};
canvas.node.onmouseup = function (e) {
         canvas.isDrawing = false;
};
```

How can I avoid breaks in large lines and make my line solid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `lineJoin` property to your canvas context?

Add the following line after you set your `lineWidth`.

```
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
```

This will *not* work if you have *closed* your path before completing rendering all the `lineTo`'s using `ctx.closePath()`.

You will have to open the path *before* you start drawing the line and close it *after* you have finished drawing the line.

Also if you move the drawing cursor using `moveTo` during drawing the `lineJoin` doesn't come into play.

You can try the following modified code (I have also included a JSFiddle link in the end).

**EDIT 1:** Updated the code as I forgot to add the `lineJoin` property to it.

**EDIT 2:** Moved the `moveTo` line to the appropriate listener method.

```
canvas.node.onmousemove = function (e) {
         if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
             return;
         }
         var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
         var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

         ctx.lineTo(x, y);
         ctx.stroke();

         canvas.lastX = x;
         canvas.lastY = y;
};
canvas.node.onmousedown = function (e) {
         canvas.isDrawing = true;
         canvas.lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
         canvas.lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

         ctx.moveTo(canvas.lastX, canvas.lastY);
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
         ctx.lineWidth = self.lineWidth();
         ctx.lineJoin = 'round';

};
canvas.node.onmouseup = function (e) {
         ctx.closePath();
         canvas.isDrawing = false;
};
```

Working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uFagt/2/).

Comment: This doesn't help me even if I use begin and close path as you show

Comment: @SergeyGavruk The `moveTo` is the issue in your case. Use the updated code in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, this helps, but I use `beginpath` and `closepath` in `onmousemove` because I need to allow parallel drawing. I receive coords by sockets and need to render this while `onmousemove` is in progress.

Comment: @SergeyGavruk Do you mean to say that you are drawing different items in the canvas at the same time? What do you do after you get the coords from the sockets? Do you render the data as text on the canvas or do you want to use them instead of the `mousemove` implementation?

Comment: Different items at the same time. So I have 2 functions: `onmousemove` and another function that does the same thing, but with coords that I receive by sockets from the server. And if do `beginPath` and `closePath` in that functions (right before and after `lineTo` and `moveTo`), both drawings are correct

Comment: @SergeyGavruk I am not aware of any way to be able to maintain the `lineJoin` while drawing another shape. An ugly approach to solve this would be to use two overlapping canvas tags instead of one. Use one canvas to draw shapes with the socket coords while the other is only used to draw the line. Since they are overlapped it would appear as if there was only one canvas tag to the end user.